# How can I rewrite the sentence more clear?

Tags: grammar, writing

I have a sentence. I want to rewrite it is more clear. Could you help me to correct it? I am not family of English. Thank you in advance

Explanation: I considered three methods: method A, B and C to measure the weight of each box. I want to measure which one is best method. To fair comparison among methods, the number of books in each box has to same. For example, if I have 8 books in box1. I will use method A to measure the weight of box1. Then I need to use same amount of book (8 books) to measure the weight using method B. The bellow sentence describer what I said. However, it is not clear to understand. Could you help me to correct it?

> To fair comparison among methods, the amount of  book in each box of referenced method is same with amount of book in compared method.

Comment: Well, for starters you would say "I want to rewrite it to be more clear" or (less attractive) "I want to rewrite it more clearly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In order to create an accurate comparison, each box used for calculating the weight contains the same number of books."

Comment: Hello, kpt. This question is not suitable for ELU (there are plenty of other websites which offer writing / editing advice). Giving an answer sends out the wrong message to other users / potential users.